# Cropping an Image in iOS App

Tags: iphone, ios, crop

I have an Image view showing the aspect fit image taken from camera or gallery. On the top of the Imageview I have placed a UIView (movable, scalable).

I want to crop the area of the image with respect to the frame of that UIView.

So i did this:

```
CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([myImageView.image CGImage], cropV.frame);// cropV is the UIview over the myImageView

UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];

CGImageRelease(imageRef);
```

The problem is when I am doing so, the actual placement of my rectangle (UIview) on the image(being large in size) is not the same.

For instance.
For a 1024x1024 image, image aoppears differently in aspect fit mode on a 320x480 screen
and if my cropV is on the frame(10,10,300,300); CGImageCreateWithImageInRect will create an image according to the 1024x1024 image.

Is there a way I can scale my cropV frame according to the image size ? so that the where ever the rectangle(cropV) is only that part is cropped.

For now I am drawing the image in the context.But this gives me blurry crops for widescreen/good HD photos.

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(myImageView.frame.size);

[myImageView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];

UIImage *viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([viewImage CGImage], cropV.frame);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get ratio on behalf of your image and view and then make your rect.

```
float ratio = yourImage.size.height/yourView.frame.size.height;
```

Try this

```
wRatio_width = myImageView.image.size.width/cropV.frame.size.width;
wRatio_height = myImageView.image.size.height/cropV.frame.size.height;
CGRect headImageRect = cropV.frame;
headImageRect.origin.x=wRatio_width * headImageRect.origin.x;
headImageRect.origin.y=wRatio_height * headImageRect.origin.y;

headImageRect.size.width=wRatio_width * headImageRect.size.width;
headImageRect.size.height=wRatio_height * headImageRect.size.height;

cropV.frame=headImageRect;
```

Comment: Can't figure out how to use this in my context ! Are you suggesting that, calculate ratio for x,y,width and Height and then multiply my cropV frame with these values ??

Comment: get ration with respect to your image(not UIImageView) and your view.

Comment: did this but I am getting full image rather than the desired crop region.By the way this is what I did, 'wRatio = myImageView.image/cropV.frame.size.width;' and then multiplying my cropV wide with the ratio. Same for height as well.

Comment: Try this
    wRatio_width = myImageView.image.size.width/cropV.frame.size.width;
    wRatio_height = myImageView.image.size.height/cropV.frame.size.height;
    CGRect headImageRect = cropV.frame;
    headImageRect.origin.x=wRatio_width * headImageRect.origin.x;
    headImageRect.origin.y=wRatio_height * headImageRect.origin.y;
    
    headImageRect.size.width=wRatio_width * headImageRect.size.width;
    headImageRect.size.height=wRatio_height * headImageRect.size.height;
    
    cropV.frame=headImageRect;

Comment: you have to make calculation according to your requirement.. i told you the way..now its up to u..